# ExpandableListView doesn't expand at all

Tags: android, list, layout, view, expand

I have ListView with 10 elements, and the last element is ExpandableListView, but when I click on the last element to expand, it doesn't expand at all, i can see only one child item where as there should be at least 5 child elements.

I tried to set layout height dynamically, but i don't know how to get real children items height.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: listviews doesnot work properly inside scrollview

Comment: you have an expandablelistview inside a listview ?

Comment: this scrollview doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you have an ExpandableListView inside a ListView? If so, I don't think it is how it should be done. What you should have is only an ExpandableListView with an ExpandableListAdapter that only return child for your 10th element. I think the documentation ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html ) explains pretty well how to create such an Adapter, but in case you need it I could paste an example.

Comment: Is this only way ? Cannot I measure height of children items, and then when i click expand icon the layout height will change dynamically ?

Comment: If you have a wrap_content, when you expand, it should grow. Anyway, I think I don't completely get your problem. Could you post some code?